# CSVLayer in the TimeSlider using ArcGIS Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, timeslider

I am trying to display the time series data in CSV using the ArcGIS Javascript API. I am working on the sample CSV layer for the timeslider, but i cant get it to show in 1 minute interval.

Answer (score 2):

You use the wrong event `map.on("layers-add-result", initSlider);`

The documentation says `layers-add-result` is fired when using `map.addLayers([])` method https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#event-layers-add-result

but you use `map.addLayer()` so, you just have to delete that little **s**

`map.on("layer-add-result", initSlider);`